# Voice channel limit in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

> Hello I am trying to make a feature where a user joins a waiting room voice channel and when he reacts with certain emoji on a message in a certain channel
> He will be dragged to a a different voice channel

So is there any way we can do this ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the vague details I've come up with this code

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    member = payload.member
    # change ... to your desired message-id and "" to your desired emoji
    if payload.message_id == ... and str(payload.emoji) == "":
        # change ... to your desired voice channel id:
        if member.voice and member.voice.channel.id == ...:
            # change ... to your "different voice channel" id
            await member.move_to(bot.get_channel(...))
        else:
            await member.send("Please join the x voice channel")
```

This uses the raw event since the normal event does not work for messages that were sent before the bot started. it checks the message-id and the emoji that was reacted with. then it checks if the member is in a voice channel, if the member is in a voice channel it checks if the voice channel is the desired one . If these fail then it DMs the member asking him to join the voice channel (x for example purposes). Then if it is that voice channel, it moves the member to another voice channel

Comment: Also is there any way that the bot can send a DM to the user whom so ever reacted if that particular VC is full ??

Comment: @user15609381 I can't seem to find any way of finding the max member count of a vc but if you know it, you can use the `bot.get_channel(...)` part and save it to a variable named `vc` for example at the start of the function, then in the `move_to` change `bot.get_channel(...`) to your variable name (e.g. `vc`). for the member checking, use `if len(vc.members) > 123` before the `move_to` and change `123` to the max member count,  hen just dm the user if that if statement passes

Comment: @user15609381 you should consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1042089) if this helped

Comment: sorry i am new to stackoverflow 
Also thanks a lot again :)